# Issue with forEach loop over array performing HTTP POST request on each object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous

I am using npm request module to perform super basic POST request against an API to upload image urls and get a new url link for each object within the array of urls. Once I have them I will push them back into my array.

I can't seem to make this work. I can get it working fine when I perform it over a regular string , but when I attempt to loop the http POST request over the array I cant get it to return.

I have an array for example:

```
var product = {
      extra_images:
        [ 'https://some.imgcdn.com/myimage1.jpg',
        'https://some.imgcdn.com/myimage2.jpg',
        'https://some.imgcdn.com/myimage3.jpg' ]
    }

product.extra_images.forEach(function(originURL, index){
          urlCloaker(originURL, extraImgResponse);
        });
```

Here is the function that performs the request to the API:

```
function urlCloaker(imgUrl, cloakedURLResponse){

  var imgUrl = 'upload=' + imgUrl;

  request('http://coolsite.com/api?' + imgUrl, function (error, response, body) {
      if(error){
        return console.log('Error:', error);
      }

      if(response.statusCode !== 200){
        return console.log('Invalid Status Code Returned:', response.statusCode);
      }
      else {
        var JSON_result = JSON.parse(body);
        cloakedURLResponse(error, JSON_result.data.img_url);
      }
  });
}
```

Here is my callback:

```
 function extraImgResponse(err, data){
      if(err)
        console.log("ERROR: " , err);
      else {
        product.extra_images.push(data);
      }

    }
```

Comment: `I cant get it to return` - you can't get what to return? what do you expect the result of your code will be?

Comment: I suspect you think `product.extra_images` will have been modified right after `product.extra_images.forEach(function ...)` - of course, as `urlCloaker` is asynchronous that can't happen straight away

Comment: extraImgResponse(err, data) when does that function gets called exactly, also are you using promises?

Comment: I am not using promises, just regular callbacks. I added a separate array to push each loops data into and then compare this arrays length to the source arrays length. When they both get to the same length the loop should stop. When I do this... I am now able to get the loop for index 1, 2 but 0 is getting skipped.

Comment: The reason it's getting skipped is because the http requests are not synchronous, so you have to wait for them to return. I suggest using promises/chaining. Callbacks can get out of hand very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by creating a separate array to compare the length of the array i was looping over doing the async requests. When the new array hit the same length as the array I was looping over , i was able to then store the data. Thank you for all your help!